# How do you pass a Class from Swift into Cocoa in order to dequeue a new UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm working on building a *UITableViewController* subclass in Swift. In order to properly use the modern

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

(or, in Swift):

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> AnyObject!
```

to get or create a *UITableViewCell*, I need to first call

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

(aka):

```
func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass!, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String!)
```

I haven't been able to find *AnyClass* in the book or other documentation, so I'm not sure how to turn a typename (in this case, *UITableViewCell*) into an *AnyClass* descriptor.

How do you do this?

Comment: how did you do it in Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the class of the cell you'd like to create at compile time, you can refer to it directly with `UITableViewCell.self`, in the same way that you'd say `[UITableViewCell class]` in Objective-C. (See "Metatype Type" in the [Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Types.html).)

It should only be necessary to use `NSClassFromString()` if you need to turn a string into a class reference at run time.

EDIT: except that in the current (first) seed, there is apparently a known bug that prevents Swift from converting a type obtained as I describe to an `AnyClass`. So this may not actually work right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [NSClassFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) method for getting the `AnyClass`.

Function signature:

```
func NSClassFromString(_ aClassName: String!) -> AnyClass!
```

Usage:

```
var cellClass:AnyClass = NSClassFromString("MyCellClassName");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I identified cellClass in my UITableViewController subclass:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
}
```